What are actually static charges and how do they get stored in objects?
This might be a stupid question but, please excuse me because I don't quite understand how static charges work.
As a kid I have been shown all those rubbing a comb or PVC pipe experiments but the only proof I got is just a statement that all these phenomena occur due to one object being statically charged or because of the exchange of charges. I also understand that object could be positively or negatively charged considering the electrons it gains or loses.
Now here is my confusion. Where do these electrons come from? Consider the PVC rubbing on the wool cloth experiment. Did electrons that charged the PVC came from molecules in the wool cloth?
Or is there a pool of electrons in the wool cloth like in a metal lattice. If then why doesn't it conduct electricity? Even if it didn't have an electron pool, it is fair to assume that a moderate potential difference would be enough to strip electrons off and make the wool cloth a conductor, since it just a few simple rubs are enough to strip these electrons off? How to explain this charging phenomenon in the atomic and molecular level?
Also, here is my second part of the question. Where do these static charges (electrons) stay in the negatively charged PVC. Once again, does it have a pool of electrons? Or do these electrons get into the orbitals in atoms, that make the PVC molecules? This further confuses me because in the first and this part of my question, if this is what's happening, how does these materials don't break down their atomic bonds in the molecules. From what I know static charges get stored on the surface in conductors, which I can understand, but I can't understand how static charges stay inside of these insulators considering all above reasons. Please explain what is wrong with my thought process and what I am missing when trying to understand above questions. For Last, I am really sorry if this is a lame question and feel free to ask for clarification if parts of my question are unintelligible.

"Did electrons that charged the PVC came from molecules in the wool cloth?" Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect

@SolomonSlow I read it but, wouldn't the electrons removing from atoms in molecules (in this case wool) make those molecules break? or do they actually break but, the number of molecules this happen is so small it is negligible? I also want to know how does van de Graff generator Works if this is true since their potential can rise so high (Ik they use different materials but you get the point).
